# Automating web form submission on page with .gsp extension

Tags: webforms, automation

I need to enter data into the following web form 2,700 times: http://sg.sensemaker-suite.com/collector/modifyfragment.gsp

I have a CSV file with all the data that needs to be entered into the form... basically an ID and a text field of several sentences. The process will be to enter the user name, password, language, and the ID. Click load. Enter a specific page number and wait for it to load. Enter field of text and click to save. Repeat this process with another line of data from the CSV.

I'd like to automate this process and would appreciate any suggestions for software or scripting resources? I've never done this before so the simpler the better. I have a comp sci background (used C/C++, Java, PHP) but have not programmed seriously in years.

Thanks!!

Comment: http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/ might be a good option for this. You should be able to quickly start by recording a submission, and then tweaking it to use with the data you want to input.

Comment: thanks @admdrew!! this seems to be working! i used this SauceLabs tutorial: http://sauceio.com/index.php/2011/01/selenium-resources-for-newbs-data-driven-testing-with-ide-xml/ and downloaded the extensions from here: http://online-selenium-trainings.webs.com/apps/blog/show/8762789-selenium-ide-parameterization.